# Postgres - Sort order is wrong

Tags: postgresql, sorting

This query:

```
with labels (label) as (
    values
        ('Asphalt Layer 2 - Labor (Hr)'::text),
        ('Asphalt Layer 2 - Labor Rate ($/Hr)'::text),
        ('Asphalt Layer 2 - Labor Cost'::text)
)
select *
from labels
order by 1;
```

Sorts the values in this order:

```
Asphalt Layer 2 - Labor Cost
Asphalt Layer 2 - Labor (Hr)
Asphalt Layer 2 - Labor Rate ($/Hr)
```

The correct order is (checked with JavaScript, too):

```
Asphalt Layer 2 - Labor (Hr)
Asphalt Layer 2 - Labor Cost
Asphalt Layer 2 - Labor Rate ($/Hr)
```

I am using AWS RDS Postgres with the following version:

`PostgreSQL 11.16 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit`

This is causing the values in a crosstab query to be transposed. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single way to sort text correctly: i.e. different languages will have different rules. So you must explicitly tell which sort order you want:

- in postgres you can use [collations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html)
- JavaScript has [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)